# What would be best approach in case of language dictionary with word types (nouns, verbs...)?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am designing an online language dictionary database, and I used a relational model. For now, I am in a stage of planning. I created most of it, but I got stuck with creating part of the database which stores word type designation (nouns, verbs, etc.). Here is the example of the database:

```
language1_words
------------------------
word1_id  int(11)  AI  PK
word1     varchar(128)

junc_lang1_lang2
------------------------
word1_id  int(11) FK(language1_words)
word2_id  int(11) FK(language2_words)

language2_words
------------------------
word2_id  int(11)  AI  PK
word2     varchar(128)
```

This is what I created for now. Now, I want to add word type table and to connect it to the previously mentioned part of the database. For every word should be corresponding word type. An example:

```
word 1 ---> noun, masculine, singular
word 2 ---> verb, transitive
word 3 ---> adjective, derived, masculine, singular
etc.
```

My question is what could be best approach to do this? I want to follow normalization rules, so I don't want to repeat entries in database, I would like to create some 'reference' table and to get word type from there. And the most important part would be ability of my online dictionary for privileged registered users to insert new words trough form, which will fill up all required cells in this RD model, so I must think also about that property when creating my database.

Comment: There is no "best" approach for this. Human languages cannot be normalized, so attempting to find the "best" approach to normalize a human language is a lost cause. Whatever approach you take will have drawbacks. The best you can hope for is some method that works for your specific use case--which means that only you can determine the best method, probably after a lot of trial and error and tweaking.

Comment: When I wrote 'best approach' I meant 'ideas' about how this problem could be approached. I know that there is always drawbacks and good choices and bad choices, but I would also like to hear other opinions and solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the proper place to solicit open-ended "ideas".

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case you are mentioning, to classify words with a type of word, what you would need is:

A table of `WordTypes` with `id` and `description`.

And from the `language1_words` and `language2_words` have a `word_type` field pointing to (foreign key) to the `WordTypes` table.

In the case that each word could have more than one type, then you would have many to many relationship you need to break.

In such case, besides of the `WordType` table you will need an additional table `WordByType` with `word_id` and `type_id`, the first one a foreign key to the `language*_words` and the second one a foreing key to the `WordType` table. 
(In this scenario you don't need to add a `word_type` field to the `language*_words` tables).

Comment: This part is understandable to me, this is what I know how to make, but the problem is with `description` part you suggested. I don't want for that part to be like `noun, masculine, singular` or `verb, transitive` (atomic columns, 1NF). I guess I should have separate tables for this word types (`table_verbs`, `table_nouns`), but for I have no idea how to design this.

Comment: Given the scenario you asked about, with a RDBMS, this would be the way to classify words by one or more types. Perhaps I haven't understood why you would want different tables for each type. It sounds to me it will be very difficult to use the data afterwards.

Comment: I don't want to put different word types in different tables. I want to make `description` of your proposed table `wordTypes`, to get values from another table for word type, which will have separate columns for each descriptor (e.g. `noun_gender`, `noun_number`). Because this table would have different descriptors based on word type (`noun ---> 2`, `verb ---> 1`, `adjective ---> 3`), I think that would be good to separate word types in different tables.